# Is this function monotone increasing?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I've made a simple model for temperature deviation in response to atmospheric CO2.

- The blue line shows historic temperature deviation data
- dotted line marks the point where I try to get the model(red line) to forecast temperature deviation should CO2 emissions be decreased to 0 by 2030

**Could I describe my model (red) as monotone increasing**, even though it plateaus towards the end? I know it cannot predict a decrease in temperature deviation.

Answer (score 0):

If this question is just about terminology, then the answer is yes. The function represented by the red line would be monotonically increasing (or weakly increasing), as opposed to strictly increasing. The former describes functions in which each subsequent value is greater than *or equal to* the previous. The latter is more limited (or strict), allowing only greater subsequent values.

Comment: Thank you. I meant terminology. I was unsure if it stopped increasing if it could still be monotonically increasing.